# Longpoll Technique or any other method

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, facebook

I have currently built a notification system with php mysql and jquery's ajax using longpolling.. The connection is kept open to the server for about 15 minutes then a new request is sent.. So in my network console the word "pending" is shown in the status of the current connection...

I have heard that website like facebook use this kind of comet approach for notifications, comments.. But the difference is that in facebook's network console... a connection is never kept open..because I didn't see the word 'pending' there..Whenever a data has to be fetched, a request is sent in facebook.. Is there something else they are using to achieve this?

So my questions are :

1. What can I do more than this keeping request open for a long time?
2. How is facebook doing it without keeping request pending?
3. Should I use something else or something more than longpolling?
4. If a request is kept pending for huge amount of time how bad it can get to RAM usage?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of long polling you can go for Socket.IO. Have a look at http://socket.io/ and http://elephant.io/

Comment: but socket.io doesn't sync with php.. I know about node.js .. I'm asking about php..

Comment: Okay. Elephant.io is a socket io client for php. But still needs node.js. Why don't you consider using node.js?

Comment: That's because of complicated algorithms I want to handle with php..not with nodejs... Php is suitable for that if I am not wrong..